# Formatar TextBox com data

Tags: datetime, textbox

Tenho aqui uma form com várias textbox e algumas combobox. O que acontece quando insiro um código e preenche a textbox com data nascimento aparece-me neste formato `01/01/1900 00:00:00` e eu só quero que apareça a data.

Podem ajudar-me?  os nomes que aparecem ai como DoctorBasic e DoctorEnterpriseDetails são nomes de tabelas e a DBO é a coluna com as datas de nascimento.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub TxtCodigoMed_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtCodigoMed.KeyPress


        If e.KeyChar.ToString = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then ' Enter para pesquisar
            TxtCodigoMed.Focus()
            e.Handled = True

            CarregarDados()

        End If


    End Sub


    Public Sub CarregarDados()
        'LblVazia.Text = 
        Dim cnnstr As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=***;user=**;password=****")
        Dim myCommand As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim table = New DataTable


        myCommand = "SELECT * FROM DoctorBasic INNER JOIN DoctorEnterpriseDetails ON DoctorBasic.DoctorId = DoctorEnterpriseDetails.DoctorId WHERE EnterpriseId = 26 AND Code = " & TxtCodigoMed.Text

        cnnstr.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, cnnstr)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(table)

        TxtPrimeiroNome.Text = table.Rows(0)("FirstName").ToString
        TxtApelido.Text = table.Rows(0)("LastName").ToString
        TxtNomeComp.Text = table.Rows(0)("FullName").ToString
        TxtDataNasc.Text = table.Rows(0)("DOB").ToString
        TxtApelido.Text = table.Rows(0)("LastName").ToString
        TxtDataForm.Text = table.Rows(0)("GraduateDate").ToString
        TxtGrauForm.Text = table.Rows(0)("Degree").ToString
        TxtTelefone.Text = table.Rows(0)("Telephone").ToString
        TxtTelem.Text = table.Rows(0)("Mobile").ToString
        TxtMail.Text = table.Rows(0)("Emailid").ToString
        TxtObs.Text = table.Rows(0)("Observation").ToString
        TxtLusov.Text = table.Rows(0)("Lusov").ToString
        Me.DoctorsAddressTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GSM81DataSet.DoctorsAddress, Me.TxtCodigoMed.Text.ToString) 'carrega a grid através da pesquisa do codigo do médico
        cnnstr.Close()


    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GSM81DataSet.GroupType' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.GroupTypeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GSM81DataSet.GroupType)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GSM81DataSet2.Rank' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.RankTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GSM81DataSet2.Rank)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GSM81DataSet1.PrescibingPotential' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PrescibingPotentialTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GSM81DataSet1.PrescibingPotential)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'GSM81DataSet.Speciality' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.SpecialityTableAdapter.Fill(Me.GSM81DataSet.Speciality)

    End Sub

    Public Sub GravarDoctorBasic()

        Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=***;user=**;password=***")
        Dim myCommand As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand


        myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorBasic SET " & _
        "Lusov = '" & TxtLusov.Text & "', " & _
      "FirstName = '" & TxtPrimeiroNome.Text & "', " & _
      "LastName = '" & TxtApelido.Text & "', " & _
      "FullName = '" & TxtNomeComp.Text & "', " & _
       "DOB = " & TxtDataNasc.Text.ToString & ", " & _
      "GraduateDate = '" & TxtDataForm.Text.ToString & "', " & _
      "Emailid = '" & TxtMail.Text & "', " & _
       "Degree = '" & TxtGrauForm.Text & "', " & _
       "Observation = '" & TxtObs.Text & "' " & _
      "WHERE DoctorId = " & TxtCodigoMed.Text.ToString

        cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
        MsgBox(myCommand)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()


    End Sub

    Public Sub GravarDoctorEnterpriseDetails()
        Dim myConnectionString As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;user=****;password=*******")
        Dim myCommand As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        myCommand = "UPDATE DoctorEnterpriseDetails SET " & _
                 "RankId = " & CBSelec.ValueMember & ", " & _
                 "GroupId = " & CBCateg.ValueMember & ", " & _
                 "PrescribingPotential = " & CBPP.ValueMember & ", " & _
                 "Telephone = " & TxtTelefone.Text & ", " & _
                 "Mobile = " & TxtTelem.Text & ", " & _
                 "Speciality1 = " & CBEsp1.ValueMember & ", " & _
                 "Speciality2 = " & CBEsp2.ValueMember & " " & _
                  "WHERE DoctorId = " & TxtCodigoMed.Text.ToString

        cmd = New SqlCommand(myCommand, myConnectionString)
        ' MsgBox(myCommand)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnGravar_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGravar.Click
        GravarDoctorBasic()
        GravarDoctorEnterpriseDetails()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `Substring`:

```
TxtDataForm.Text = table.Rows(0)("GraduateDate").ToString().Substring(0, IIf(table.Rows(0)("GraduateDate").ToString().Length > 10, 10, table.Rows(0)("GraduateDate").ToString().Length))
```

Ou fazendo `Casting`:

```
TxtDataForm.Text = CType(table.Rows(0)("GraduateDate").ToString(), DateTime).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: usei a primeira e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigada, também estou com problemas em fazer update. tenho que abrir um novo topico para pedir ajuda?

Comment: Seria bom, pois assim separa os assuntos.

Comment: só ha um pequeno problema.. dá-me este erro na linha da substring  " O índice e o comprimento têm de fazer referência a uma localização na cadeia de caracteres.
Nome do parâmetro: length " (isto apareceu-me quando inseri um medico sem data de nascimento)

Comment: Verifique agora, editei a resposta com uma verificação.

Comment: sim é isso mesmo!